# Установка CentOS к Windows 7

Tags: centos, windows-7

Сам работаю под Windows7, cтавил на виртуалку CentOS 6.7 и заметил там один пункт при выборе раздела для оси: подвинуть старую систему и сделать ещё раздел. Т.е. я правильно понимаю, что если у меня один логический диск с виндой, на котором 100 Гб свободно, то я могу из этих 100 выделить 50, создать новый раздел, и в итоге у меня будет два логических диска, один с W7, другой с CentOS, и я смогу загружаться на любую систему? Нужно ли предварительно сделать дефрагментацию? Нужно ли будет что-то делать с загрузочными записями (ибо как правильно сделать так, чтобы при загрузке у меня спрашивали какую ось грузануть я не знаю)?

Comment: Такое можно сделать. Если Linux установить вторым, то boot-сектор не  надо править.

Comment: Нужно ли делать дефрагментацию? Я имею в виду если у меня один физический диск с 1 логическим разделом, на котором файлы раскиданы хаотично (ну т.е. на разных цилиндрах и секторах), нужно ли их как-то сдвинуть в кучку? Или при разбиении на логические разделы это не имеет никакого значения?

Answer (score 1):

если ставится в виртуальной машине, то загрузка может быть только из виртуальной машине. Захват физического раздела ни о чем не говорит, да и не нужен, по большому счету. Если выделять кусок диска под физический раздел, то конечно лучше дефрагментировать радел, который будет уменьшен, во избежание потери данных

Comment: Не не не, имеется в виду не на виртуалку ставить, а на физическую машину. Просто я сначала поставил на виртуалку под W7, а потом начал думать поставить на свой комп одновременно W7 и CentOS.
Проблема вся в том, что под виндой у меня довольно много нужных мне программ стоит, и работа там более-менее стабильна. Не хочется самому себе создавать проблемы -- если что-то пойдёт не так и мне придётся форматировать диск и ставить систему заново.

Comment: тогда просто дефрагментировать диск, каким то ауронисом или clonezilla сдвинуть раздел, выделив место и все. После установки будет 2 системы, с запросом при загрузке, какую грузить. У меня так стоит